# Quadratic n term equation using multiindex

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe, multi-index, quadratic

I have two DFs which I would like to use to calculate the following:

```
w(ti,ti)*a(ti)^2 + w(tj,tj)*b(sj,tj)^2 + 2*w(si,tj)*a(ti)*b(tj)
```

The above uses two terms (a,b).
w is the weight df where i and j are index and column spaces pertaining to the Tn index of a and b.

**Set Up - Edit dynamic W**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

I = ['i'+ str(i) for i in range(4)]
Q = ['q' + str(i) for i in range(5)]
T = ['t' + str(i) for i in range(3)]
n = 100

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'I': [I[np.random.randint(len(I))] for i in range(n)],
                    'Q': [Q[np.random.randint(len(Q))] for i in range(n)],
                    'Tn': [T[np.random.randint(len(T))] for i in range(n)],
                    'V': np.random.rand(n)}).groupby(['I','Q','Tn']).sum()

df1.head(5)
I  Q  Tn  V        
i0 q0 t0  1.626799
      t2  1.725374
   q1 t0  2.155340
      t1  0.479741
      t2  1.039178

w = np.random.randn(len(T),len(T))
w = (w*w.T)/2
np.fill_diagonal(w,1)
W = pd.DataFrame(w, columns = T, index = T)

W
          t0        t1        t2
t0  1.000000  0.029174 -0.045754
t1  0.029174  1.000000  0.233330
t2 -0.045754  0.233330  1.000000
```

Effectively I would like to use the index Tn in df1 to use the above equation for every I and Q.

The end result for `df1.loc['i0','q0']` in the example above should be:

```
  W(t0,t0) * V(t0)^2 
+ W(t2,t2) * V(t2)^2
+ 2 * W(t0,t2) * V(t0) * V(t2) 
=     
  1.0 * 1.626799**2 
+ 1.0 * 1.725374**2 
+ (-0.045754) * 1.626799 * 1.725374
```

The end result for `df1.loc['i0','q1']` in the example above should be:

```
  W(t0,t0) * V(t0)^2 
+ W(t1,t1) * V(t1)^2
+ W(t2,t2) * V(t2)^2
+ 2 * W(t0,t1) * V(t0) * V(t1)
+ 2 * W(t0,t2) * V(t0) * V(t2)
+ 2 * W(t2,t1) * V(t1) * V(t2)
=     
  1.0 * 2.155340**2 
+ 1.0 * 0.479741**2
+ 1.0 * 1.039178**2
+ 0.029174 * 2.155340 * 0.479741 * 1
+ (-0.045754) * 2.155340 * 1.039178 * 1
+ 0.233330 * 0.479741 * 1.039178 * 1
```

This pattern will repeat depending on the number of tn terms in each Q hence it should be robust enough to handle as many Tn terms as needed (in the example I use 3, but it could be as much as 100 or more).

Each result should then be saved in a new DF with `Index = [I, Q]`
The solution should also not be slower than excel when `n` increases in value.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your equation implies the value 'w' is the same for all three terms but they are not. Maybe you should rename them and describe how they relate to or are derived from the df1 *indices* . Make it easier for your *readers*.

Comment: `df1.loc['i0','q0'` has three `Tn`'s. How does it work?

Comment: Is `W` not supposed to be symmetric? if not, how I know which factor to used between `W.loc['t3','t4']` and `W.loc['t4','t3']` for the example you give, because you use the first one but why?

Comment: I have changed the question to correspond with the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way could be first `reindex` your dataframe `df1` with all the possible combinations of the lists `I`, `Q` and `Tn` with `pd.MultiIndex.from_product`, filling the missing value in the column 'V' with 0. The column has then `len(I)*len(Q)*len(T)` elements. Then you can `reshape` the `values` to get each row related to one combination on `I` and `Q` such as:

```
ar = (df1.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([I,Q,T], names=['I','Q','Tn']),fill_value=0)
         .values.reshape(-1,len(T)))
```

To see the relation between my input `df1` and `ar`, here are some related rows

```
print (df1.head(6))
                 V
I  Q  Tn          
i0 q0 t1  1.123666
   q1 t0  0.538610
      t1  2.943206
   q2 t0  0.570990
      t1  0.617524
      t2  1.413926
print (ar[:3])
[[0.         1.1236656  0.        ]
 [0.53861027 2.94320574 0.        ]
 [0.57099049 0.61752408 1.4139263 ]]
```

Now, to perform the multiplication with the element of `W`, one way is to create the outer product of `ar` with itself but row-wise to get, for each row a `len(T)*len(T)` matrix. For example, for the second row:

```
[0.53861027 2.94320574 0.        ]
```

becomes

```
[[0.29010102, 1.58524083, 0.        ], #0.29010102 = 0.53861027**2, 1.58524083 = 0.53861027*2.94320574 ...
 [1.58524083, 8.66246003, 0.        ],
 [0.        , 0.        , 0.        ]]
```

Several methods are possible such as `ar[:,:,None]*ar[:,None,:]` or `np.einsum` with the right subscript: `np.einsum('ij,ik->ijk',ar,ar)`. Both give same result.

The next step can be done with a `tensordot` and specify the right `axes`. So with `ar` and `W` as an input, you do:

```
print (np.tensordot(np.einsum('ij,ik->ijk',ar,ar),W.values,axes=([1,2],[0,1])))
array([ 1.26262437, 15.29352438, 15.94605435, ...
```

To check for the second value here, `1*0.29010102 + 1*8.66246003 + 2.*2*1.58524083 == 15.29352438` (where 1 is `W(t0,t0)` and `W(t1,t1)`, 2 is `W(t0,t1)`)

Finally, to create the dataframe as expected, use again `pd.MultiIndex.from_product`:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': np.tensordot(np.einsum('ij,ik->ijk',ar,ar),
                                            W.values,axes=([1,2],[0,1]))},
                      index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([I,Q], names=['I','Q']))

print (new_df.head(3))
            col1
I  Q            
i0 q0   1.262624
   q1  15.293524
   q2  15.946054
...
```

Note: if you are **SURE** that each element of `T` is at least once in the last level of `df1`, the `ar` can be obtain using `unstack` such as `ar=df1.unstack(fill_value=0).values`. But I would suggest to use the `reindex` method above to prevent any error

Comment: This seems to work. However, I found an edge case in my problem which would make this answer not correct. Otherwise you have taught me something new! Thank you

Comment: @RealRageDontQuit what you call edge case is actually a different problem. You change the dataframe structure by adding an index level, change the formula by multipying with another matrix `s`  and do a sum over this new index (at least of what I understood). I think my answer can pretty easily be adapted to this problem, but if you want a general method it will be more complicated.

Comment: you are correct to say that this question solves the initial problem. I have changed the question to reflect the initial problem, tick your answer as accepted (thanks) and will also create a new question with this edge case.